# override amp css with custom css - AMP wordpress

Tags: html, css, amp-html, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to override few css properties to make the amp version of the page look alike the non-amp version. But I am unable to do so even after adding in the custom css section under the amp design settings. Since !important doesnt work in amp, how can I override a certain property.

For example, this is the css in amp :

```
   .ampstart-nav-item {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: pink;
    }
```

I am trying to overrride the background color to blue using in the custom css section under Design>Global> Custom css in the AMP plugin:

```
.ampstart-nav-item {
       background-color: blue;
 }
```

But the existing amp generated css overrides the custom css. What can be done in this case?

Comment: Are you using a child theme? If you use the styles in it, it will have higher priority.

Comment: Yes, I am using a child theme. So you mean instead of adding the amp only css in the custom css of the amp plugin, i should be using it in the child theme's custom css?

Comment: Let's see what happens.

Comment: Just tried, it doesnt help.

Comment: Okay you can try using a better specificity. For example: `.parent-element .ampstart-nav-item` will have higher priority.

Comment: Unforunately that did not work as well. :\ I also tried to inject the code with a hook from functions.php still no luck.

Comment: Can you ask the plugin guys then?

Comment: Sure. Will update here if i find a proper solution.

Comment: The Custom CSS should be getting added to the page after other CSS is being included, so you shouldn't have to give the selector higher specificity. Please share details, including your theme, whether you're using the official AMP plugin, and how the CSS is being enqueued. Lastly, please share the entire page source of the AMP page, such as in a Gist.